# Are these structures in the same language?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have these teo structures, $(N, <)$ and $(Q, <)$. And I want to know if they can come from the same language?

I'm confused about the definition I have for an La-structure. Specefically about domains. And I am hung up on how much what the set $A$ is (defined below) does or does not matter.

Here's the def i'm working with:

An La-structure is a pair $(M, I)$ as follows.

1. $M \neq \{\}$
2. $I$ is a function with domain $A$ (I'll write what $A$ is next) such that for each $I \in N$ the following conditions hold:

   1. If $c_i $ is in $A$ the  $I( c_i )$ is in $M$
   2. If $F_i $ is in $ A $ , then $I(F_i )$ is a function $I(F_i ):  M^n \to M$, where $n$ equals the arity of $F_i $
   3. If $(P_i )$ is in $ A $, then $I(P_i )$ is a subset of $ M^n$ where $n$ is the arity of $P_i $.

Okay. Now to define $ A $, as well as La-formulas:

- A finite sequence $\beta$ is a La-formulas iff $\beta$ is a formula, and the constant,  predicate, and function symbols of our language are all occuring in $ A $.

Comment: Um, $A$ should contain _all_ the non-logical symbols of the language. In this case it looks like $A$ contains exactly one symbol, a binary predicate.

Comment: Then isnt A the same for every structure out there? And how can it be the domain for <?

Comment: I suppose that with La you are meaning something like $\mathcal L_A$ where $A$ is an *alphabet*, i.e. a set of "constant, predicate, and function symbols". If so an $\mathcal L$-structure $\mathcal M$ is given by : i) a nonempty set $M$ called the *universe* or *domain*; ii) a function $f_i^M : M^n \to M$ for each function symbol $f_i$ (i.e. an *interpretation* for the symbol $f$; your $I(f_i)$ ); etc.

Comment: In your example, the language $\mathcal L_A$ must have as *alphabet* $A = \{ < \}$. We have to interpret "<" in the two structure as the order "less than" between *natural* numbers in $(\mathbb N, <)$ and between *rational* numbers in $(\mathbb Q, <)$.

Comment: In that case, the structurea cant come from the same language. But then, what can M be?

Comment: Okay, thanks. I definatley had (have) some misunderstandings. I guess of the purposes of my problem $A$ is a lanugage eith one binary relation. Okay. I made some changes to the definiton of $ A $ above because how I wrote it was wrong

Comment: @MerryMC: $M$ is $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q$ in the two examples, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notations $(\mathbb N,{<})$ and $(\mathbb Q,{<})$ are slightly abbreviated compared to your formal definition.

You're working in a language containing a single binary predicate $p_1^2$, so $A=\{p_1^2\}$.

The structures the question is about would, more rigidly, be written $(\mathbb N,\{p_1^2\mapsto {<_\mathbb N}\})$ and $(\mathbb Q,\{p_1^2\mapsto {<_\mathbb Q}\})$, where e.g. $\{p_1^2\mapsto {<_\mathbb N}\}$ is the function that maps the single element of $A$ to the relation $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\mid x<y\}$.

Thus, in your two examples, the $M$ are $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q$ respectively, $A$ is $\{p_1^2\}$ in both cases, and $I$ maps $p_1^2$ to the appropriate less-than relation for $M$.

This abbreviated format is very common: When there's a particular conventional (or implied) order to list the elements of $A$, we will usually simply write $(M,I(a_1),I(a_2),\ldots,I(a_n))$ instead of $(M,I)$. This is usually more readable than using a lot of boilerplate formalism to wrap the $I$ up as a function object.